# spring-cloud-stream retry policy per exception

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-retry

In the documentation of the spring-cloud-stream project the only retry mechanism that I have saw was a single backoff policy.
The behavior that I would like to achieve is three different retry policies in case that an exception is thrown while consuming a message:

1. Unrecoverable exception - this kind of messages wouldn't be tried to be processed again.
2. Recoverable exception - this kind of messages would be retried number of times before being discarded.
3. Transient exception - this kind of messages would be retried forever.

Is there a way to define a different retry policy for each kind of exception?
I know that in spring-kafka there was an ability to provide a RetryTemplate and achieve the above-mentioned behavior.

I thought that maybe with the DLQ mechanism there would be a way to achieve this behavior.

Edit: I am using Kafka as the messaging middleware.

Comment: i'm using '2020.0.4' of spring cloud and when i return null value (when i need to skip this message), this request ignore with spring and not try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.0 upwards you can define your own `RetryTemplate` :

```java
@StreamRetryTemplate
public RetryTemplate myRetryTemplate() {
    return new RetryTemplate();
}
```

Full doc here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_template

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to configure the retry to that extent; there is [an open new feature request](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/858).

However, you can always implement your own logic within your listener, using a `RetryTemplate` and disable the binder's retries.

If you are using the Rabbit binder, you could use the DLQ and `republishToDlq=true` and the DLQ messages will contain exception headers. You can then have another app consume those messages and take appropriate action based on the exception type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW I am using Kafka and edited the question. I thought about implementing the retry inside my listener but I wondered if it wouldn't cause a timeout in the consumer specifically in case of a transient exception. Unless of course if the timeout would be configured with a high value.

Comment: The listener container will take of heartbeats and will pause the consumer if the listener is slow.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the answer. The scenario that I am talking about is a message processing logic inside the listener that throws a transient exception and a RetryTemplate that wrappers the logic and in case of a transient exception it uses an AlwaysRetryPolicy. In this scenario the listener would be "stuck" and try to process this message over and over again until it succeeds, and this can take a few minutes and maybe even more (until the problem is fixed somehow). In this case the consumer won't be timed out? So using a RetryTemplate would not be good in this case.

Comment: Typo, I meant "take care of heartbeats". Prior to client version 0.10.1.0 [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread), kafka would rebalance if a listener didn't respond. We added code to deal with that, detect a slow consumer and continue to send heartbeats in the background; if the consumer is slow, we temporarily `pause()` the consumer. Since KIP-62 this is not necessary since the client now handles heartbeats in the background; the broker can tell the difference between a slow and dead consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
UnrecoverableException = exception you want to go to the DLQ or discarded right away without retry.
TransientException = exception you want to be retried until successful

Something like this in my config class made it work:

```
@StreamRetryTemplate
public RetryTemplate myRetryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate myRetry = RetryTemplate.builder()
            .notRetryOn(UnrecoverableException.class)
             //make sure that the exception type is the cause
             //even if it's wrapped 
            .traversingCauses()
            .retryOn(TransientException.class)
            .traversingCauses()
             //custom backoff policy
            .exponentialBackoff(2000, 2, 20000, true)
            .build();
    return myRetry;
}
```